# Custom Font Thumbnail

Tags: file-browser

Is it possible currently to replace the text in the Thumbnails font preview with a user defined text?
Currently it displays default text that may not be helpful in searching for match for specific letter in the font because most of the letters are too small.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, that font-preview text is defined statically in code (only 'customization' allowed is its translation, such that e.g. Chinese or Arabic languages can show some relevant glyphs…).